# Embedded schema dropdown list with a single keyword value not included in XML

Tags: cme, content-manager

I have a content schema that contains an embedded schema with a text field that is populated from a category:

```
FooSchema
    |
    - heading (text field)
    - offers (embedded schema field)
         |
         - offer (component)
         - area  (category drop-down list)
```

When the category that populates the "area" drop-down list only contains a single item, the value does not get included in the component XML. It looks something like this:

```
<Foo xmlns="uuid:4089297c-34a4-4c61-bb0e-4f7a0f9fd138">   
    <heading>test</heading>
    <offers>
        <offer xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:13-27777" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></offer>
    </offers>
</Foo>
```

Because the offer and area fields are both required, attempting to save new components results in an XML validation error. As a workaround, we added a second keyword to the category, which allows the content editors to select the second item and then select the first item.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there a fix, or a better workaround?

Comment: I've checked this works as expected in 2013 SP1 HR1 - tested with a mandatory field linked to a single keyword and an optional field linked to a single keyword. Have you checked you're not missing a hotfix for your implementation?

Comment: perhaps post the XML schema for review...

Comment: may be you can define the categories and keywords on the same level and define the schema for that field as default value